# How to show the soap calls log in spring boot app running in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, soap

I have a spring boot application,

- Packaged as war file
- Deployed in a tomcat 9.x
- The web app is calling third-party web-services using **SOAP**.

My problem was how to show the SOAP logs specifically in Tomcat container, because I can show the logs in Spring boot using the following code in Application's main method

```
 System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "999999");
```

But this didn't work in tomcat server.
I have found the below post to build a Soap Handler to log requests:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27468517/716865

What happened is the third-part responded with **invalid name space error**

Answer (score 1):

After long investigation, I have found the following simple solution:

1. Edit yout **catalina.sh**/**catalina.bat** file which can be found in your tomcat installation
2. Add the following lines or append to CATALINA_OPTS:

   **CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold=999999"**
3. Restart your tomcat server
4. Call the webservice from the web app, you will find all soap requests fully logged

> Be aware, that this could lead to security concerns if the soap requests/response has sensitive data.

I believe there could be better solutions than mine, but this workss perfectly for me without adding any extra piece of code.